# Javascript - Pegar resultado do for e colocar cada resultado dentro de um array

Tags: array, matriz

Olá, alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão.
Gostaria de colocar cada resultado dentro de minha nova array.

Exemplo, meu for gera o resultado de 9 Array.

```
success: function(res){

        for(i in res){
            var dados = [
                [res[i].nome, res[i].sobrenome]
            ];
            console.log(pos);
        }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que cada espaço de minha nova array seja preenchido com cada resultado do meu for, resultado 1 no espaço 0 da nova array, resultado 2 no espaço 1 da nova array etc....

```
var result = new Array('','','','','','','','','',);
console.log(result);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não encontrei uma forma de fazer isso em Javascript, se alguém poder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pode tentar assim

```
success: function(res){
        let dados = [];
        for(let i in res){
            dados.push(
                [res[i].nome, res[i].sobrenome]
            );
        }
        console.log(dados);
    }
```

### Bônus

Existem outras formais mais fáceis de fazer isso com javascript, segue um exemplo:

```
success: function(res){
    let dados = res.map(
        item => [item.nome, item.sobrenome]);
    console.log(dados);
}
```

Comment: É exatamente isso,  Muito obrigado. Preciso estudar sobre push e map vlw.